# "jsonschema" not validating schema in Python

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

The JSON records should be invalid but its showing the value to be True

```
import json
import jsonschema
dat='{"TID":"9020","CUR":"USD","DAT1":"t","DAT2":11}'

print type(dat)
def validJson(rowData):
    jsonRec=json.loads(rowData)
    jsonSc=json.loads('''{  "title": "NCAP", "type": "object",  "properties": { "TID" : { "type ": [ "string" ]  },"CUR" : { "type ": [ "string" ]  , "maxLength" : 3 },"DAT1" : { "type ": [ "number","null"]  , "maximum" : 99999999999 },"DAT2" : { "type ": [ "number" ,"null"]  , "maximum" : 112 } },  "required": [  "TID",  "CUR",  "DAT1",  "DAT2" ] }''')
    val = jsonschema.Draft3Validator(jsonSc).is_valid(jsonRec)
    print "is records valid ::"+str( val)
    va=jsonschema.validate(jsonRec, jsonSc)
    print "records validated "+str(va)
    return json.dumps(jsonRec)

print validJson(dat)
```

The reason why it should be False is that DAT1 datatype is number while its value is "t"

Or if anyone can suggest some a way where it the json records gets validated with respect to its Schema

Comment: Why do you think it should be invalid?

Comment: i checked it using http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and it was fine

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The reason why it should be False is that DAT1 datatype is number while its value is "t"

Comment: @Salman but it should be False as DAT1 datatype is number while its value is "t"

Answer (score 0):

You have a space after your `type` keyword. Json Schema doesn't recognize that as a keyword and ignores it.  Get rid of that extra space and it will work as expected.